# Axis in python plots

Tags: python, plot

I need to plot multiple plots in the same figures, something like this:

[image]

The code is roughly like this:

```
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(16, 12))
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, '$\mathrm{V_{Gas}^{HI}}$ [km/s]', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, '$\mathrm{W_{50}^{median}}$', va='center', rotation='vertical')

for i in range (1,13):
    ax = plt.subplot(3,4,i)
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 50, color='red',histtype='step', weights=weight)
    plt.plot((a,b), (maxim, maxim),"b-")
    plt.plot((a-c/2,a), (maxim, maxim),"b--")
    plt.plot((b,b+c/2), (maxim, maxim),"b--")
```

So basically I plot the histogram and some lines on it. My question is why the first plot doesn't have the label on x-axis?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque what version of Python do you use?

Comment: 3.4.4 ipython in a Jupyter notebook - matplotlib 1.5.1

Comment: @ReblochonMasque it is still not working...